# Trying to add annotations to my map in Titanium 3.4

Tags: dictionary, annotations, titanium

I'm trying to add annotations to my map in Titanium and I keep ending up with this error:

"line = 37;

message = "Invalid type passed to function";

Invalid type passed to function"

nativeLocation = "-[TiMapViewProxy annotationFromArg:] (TiMapViewProxy.m:120)";

nativeReason = "expected: Object, was: NSNull";"

Here's my code. As far as I know it should work.

```
//This is the code to implement a map and store locations using annotations
var locationsTabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
    barColor: '#E62B2B'
});


var locationsToHome = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title: 'Back',
titleAttributes: {
color: 'white'
},
backgroundImage: 'images/revisedbackbutton2.png',
height: 35,
width: 80,
borderRadius: 10
});

var locationsWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    leftNavButton: locationsToHome,
    title:'Select Store',
    tabBarHidden: true,
    titleAttributes:  {
        color:'white'
       }
});

var MapModule = require('ti.map');

var locationsMap = MapModule.createView({
    mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
    animate: true,
    region: {latitude: -27.962939, longitude: 153.382428, latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1 },
    height: '100%',
    top: 0,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    annotations: [store1]
});

var store1 = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude: -27.465868,
    longitude: 153.028309,
    pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED,   
    title: 'Pita Pit Brisbane',
    subtitle: '280 Adelaide St, Brisbane QLD 4000'
});

var store2 = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude: -27.499154,
    longitude: 152.972711,
    pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED,   
   title: 'Pita Pit Indooroopilly',
    subtitle: '322 Moggill Rd, Indooroopilly QLD 4068'
});

var store3 = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude: -27.453312,
    longitude: 153.034908,
    pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED,   
    title: 'Pita Pit Green Square',
    subtitle: '6/515 St Pauls Terrace, Fortitude Valley QLD 4006'
});

var locationsTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    window: locationsWindow
});

locationsWindow.add(locationsMap);
locationsTabGroup.addTab(locationsTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the annotation before it is created.
You should declare all your annotations before passing them to the map.

Or don't set the annotations at creation and use `locationsMap.setAnnotations([store1, store2, store3]);` once your annotations have been declared.